# LaTeX creating unwanted files in Temp folder

Tags: compiling

My problem is the following: every time I compile a document, strange-named .tex files (+ their .log files) appear in my c:\Temp directory (the file names are always 2 letters + 4 numbers). These files contain only a few lines of code, as the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{currfile}
\AtBeginOfEveryFile{\message{^^Jentering file \currfilename ^^J}}
\AtEndOfEveryFile{\message{^^Jleaving file \currfilename ^^J}}
\tracingonline=1
\tracingassigns=1
\usepackage{t1enc}
\tracingassigns=0
\AtBeginOfEveryFile{}
\AtEndOfEveryFile{}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I tried to use TeXStudio and TeXMaker as well, but compiling always results in the creation of these kind of files. What is the meaning of this code? Is this some kind of virus? I am worried, because I read an article about LaTeX viruses creating files in Temp folder... If that is the case, what can I do against it?

Comment: Does this happen if you do `pdflatex <filename>` at the Command Prompt? I wonder if you are seeing some feature of an editor (you don't say, but the comment on TeXStudio/TeXmaker suggests there is a GUI involved).

Comment: LaTeX creating virus files in Temp? Where did you read it?

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
#1: I use GUI, indeed. Now I tried compiling at the Command prompt, and it does not produce these kind of files in Temp directory. Does it mean that it is a feature of the editor(s) and not a virus for sure?
#2: I read two articles about LaTeX viruses:
https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/73506-checkoway.pdf and
https://hovav.net/ucsd/dist/texhack.pdf
I did not fully understand them (I am not an expert, just a simple user...), but I got an impression that it might be a virus. Therfore I decided to ask here.